# Displaying a comlex listview in Android

Tags: android, listview, typeface

I'm working on an Android project that needs a ListView like this:
[image]

Each row has three parts with different fonts and alignments. To be honest, I examined a lot of ideas, but did not succeed. Your guidance and help will be highly appreciated.

Regards.

---

CODE

---

### CategoryActivity.java

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list = 
                new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>(); 

public class CategoryActivity extends ListActivity 
{

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.category);

        list.clear();
         SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    this,
                    list,
                    R.layout.custom_row_view,
                    new String[] {"contents"},
                    new int[] {R.id.text1}
                    );
            populateList();
            setListAdapter(adapter);


    }

 private void populateList() 
    {
        HashMap<String,String> temp;
        for(int i=0;i<contents.length;i++)
        {
            temp = new HashMap<String,String>();
            temp.put("contents", contents[i]);
            temp.put("str", str[i]);
            temp.put("counts", counts[i]+"");
            list.add(temp);
        }

    }
.

.
.
}
```

---

### custom_row_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">

    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        android:stretchColumns="0"
         android:background="#00000000"
    >

    <TableRow>


         <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:textColor="#FF0000"   
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:textSize="30px"
         android:paddingRight="10dip" 
        >
    </TextView>


<TextView android:id="@+id/text1"         
    android:textColor="#FF0000"   
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"


    android:layout_gravity="right" />       



    </TableRow>


  </TableLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

---

### And finally category.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >



 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mylayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">


        <ListView 
        android:id="@id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#000fff"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false">
    </ListView>

</FrameLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Actually the above code does not implement what picture shows, exactly, but it's so close to what I used. Your suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: Please show your custom item layout.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a custom list layout and your own adapter. Look for "ListView tutorial"

Comment: You are right, but I could not do it successfully. My main problem is that, I can not change typefaces. Would you please provide me a simple code ? Or any clue? Regards.

Comment: Setting a TextView's font is pretty simple. Post your code so we cansee what's wrong.

Comment: I have edited the question. My code is there. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Changing typeface to bold can be achieved in XML by:

```
android:textStyle="bold"
```

or via code by:

```
.setTypeface(Typeface.BOLD);
```